# Laravel vue duplicates data

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I'm trying to add new data to old one's without refreshing page, *the issue is when I add new one not only new data but old data return with it as well*.

`Example`

Here I have `2` bid (old data)

[image: one]

When I add new bid it supposed to become `3` instead it becomes `5`

[image: two]

> which means my `2` old data stays as they are and again they return
>   with new one `3` total becomes `5`

## Code `commented`

```
data() {
    return {
        bid: { //send bid to back-end (form)
            attachment: '',
            message: '',
            bid: '',
            project_id: '',
            user_id: '',
        },
        biders: [],  //return old bids info
        new_biders: '',
    }
},
mounted: function () {
    this.getBidders(); // get old bids info
},
sendbid() { //send bid form data to back-end
    let project_id = this.project.id;
    let message = this.bid.message;
    let user_id = this.user.id;
    let attachment = this.bid.attachment;
    let bid = this.bid.bid;
    axios.post('/api/sendbid', {project_id, user_id, message, attachment, bid})
        .then(response => {
            $(".bidmsg").append('<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">Thank you dear <b>' + this.user.name + '</b> your bid placed successfully.</div>');
            //get new bid data and add it to previous ones
            this.$nextTick(function () {
                this.getBidders();
            });
        });
},
getBidders: function () { // get previous (old data) bids info
    let url = `/api/projects/${this.$route.params.slug}`
    axios.get(url).then(function (response) {
        this.project = response.data;
        axios.post('/api/projectbids/' + this.project.id)
            .then(function (res) {
                _.forEach(res.data, function (item) {
                        this.biders.push(item);
                    }.bind(this)
                )
            }.bind(this))
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error.response)
            });

        Echo.private('newbidplaced.' + this.project.id)
            .listen('NewBider', function (e) {
                this.biders.push(e.bider);
            }.bind(this));

        Vue.nextTick(function () {
            $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
        });
    }.bind(this));

}
```

## Question

1. How can I only return new data without old ones?

this part in `sendbid()`:

```
this.$nextTick(function () {
  this.getBidders();
});
```

Comment: when you are adding new bid ,In response you are getting all the bids not the one added and then you are appending it to the existing one so its duplicating data.So I think one way is return only those that are added last.

Comment: You're only ever pushing to the bidder's array, never pruning: `this.biders.push(item);`. Do you mean to do `this.bidders.splice(0, this.bidders.length, res.data)`?

Comment: @MayuriPansuriya exactly that's my issue (i'm aware of that, as i call my `getBidders()`) but the issue is i don't know how to return only new one?

Comment: @DigitalDrifter i'm getting `Error in nextTick: "TypeError: this.bidders is undefined"` with splice method.

Comment: You've spelt it `biders`, one d.

Comment: @DigitalDrifter sorry I'm newbie in vue i didn't get your point.

Comment: the data property: `biders:[],  //return old bids info`, I used two d's in my spelling.

Comment: `this.biders.splice(0, this.biders.length, ...res.data)` That should work for you.

Comment: @DigitalDrifter ok, now instead of add new one to olds it removes all and return only new one, what i want is for example i have 2 it become 3 not to become 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to push the element you just added, `getBidders` is not really necessary, but if you want to still use `getBidders`, you have to clone the response instead of pushing to the array, since it already has those values. Or check in `this.bidders` if the object already exist in the array.

You can try at least refreshing the array, but it may flash on the page...

**Sol1**

```js
this.bidders = [] // empty the array before adding new data
_.forEach(res.data, function(item){
   this.bidders.push(item);
}.bind(this)
```

**Sol2**

As i said before, you should return the saved element at `sendbid()` method.

And add this element to bidders. That would be a more appropiate approach.

Just append (push) or prepend (unshift), instead of calling the getBidders function...

```js
this.bidders.push(response);
this.bidders.unshift(response);
```

Should end up with something like

```js
axios.post('/api/sendbid', {project_id, user_id, message, attachment, bid})
.then(response => {

    if(response.data.status == 'ok'){
        $(".bidmsg").append('<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">Thank you dear <b>'+this.user.name+'</b> your bid placed successfully.</div>');
        // use either push or unshif not both, of course you already know that.
        this.bidders.push(response.data.bid);
        this.bidders.unshift(response.data.bid);

    }


});
```

Also in the function that gets called by `api/sendbid` route... add something like:

Assuming you have a Bid Model, and that you just saved a bider;

```php
    $bid->save(); //when you call the save function automatically updates the inserted id.

    $data['status'] = 'ok';
    $data['bid'] = Bid::findOrFail($bid->id); //this will refresh the element so everything is passed correctly.

    return response()->json($data);
```

Comment: have you installed lodash?

Comment: now that would work, just 1 issue, the kind of data that i get is undefined, see here please https://www.photobox.co.uk/my/photo?album_id=5394651990&photo_id=500990950074

Comment: modify your controllers to respond with the item that you just saved

Comment: @mafortis i updated my answer to show you how your controller should look

Comment: Refresh your item by calling findOrFail, as in my example

Comment: sorry my code was wrong i fixed it please see the link again.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
let removeIndex = this.yourData.map(function (data) {
                                    return data.id;
                                }).indexOf(id);
                                this.yourData.splice(removeIndex, 1);
```

hope this helps

Comment: replace this with my `$nextTick` ?

Comment: replace ` _.forEach(res.data, function (item) {
                        this.biders.push(item);
                    }.bind(this)
                )` with this code where this.yourData is this.biders